# Why does Cassandra throw ReadRepairStage errors when read_repair_chance = 0.0?

Tags: cassandra

Bonjour tout le monde,

We see in the Cassandra logs some errors like:

```
ERROR [ReadRepairStage:24984] 2022-10-18 10:05:32,622 CassandraDaemon.java:228 - Exception in thread Thread[ReadRepairStage:24984,5,main]
```

However we have deactivated the read repair

Notre environnement:

- Cassandra: 3.11.5
- Cluster replication: RF 3 with DC1 : 1, DC2 : 1, DC3 : 1
- read repair settings of all tables: dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.0 and read_repair_chance = 0.0

Does anyone have an explanation ? Thank you, Flo

Answer (score 0):

[Read repairs](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/operating/read_repair.html) are not just triggered by the read repair chance properties of a table.

Read repairs get triggered by the coordinator when the following conditions are true:

1. there is more than one replica involved in the read (request consistency is higher than `ONE` or `LOCAL_ONE`), AND
2. there is a mismatch in the result digest returned (one or more replicas is out-of-date).

For example, for a read request with a consistency of `LOCAL_QUORUM` and a replication factor of 3, the coordinator will:

- send a DIRECT read request from one of the replicas, and
- send a DIGEST read request (hash/checksum only, not actual data) to another replica.

The coordinator will then hash the data of the direct read request and compare it to the digest from the other replica. If they match, the data is returned to the client/driver. If there is a digest mismatch, the coordinator triggers a read repair to fix the inconsistent replica then the data is returned to the client/driver.

This type of read repair is referred to as "blocking" because the result does not get returned to the client until the faulty replica(s) is repaired. The coordinator will always trigger this type of read repair if there is a digest mismatch. It is not dependent on read repair chance.

For more information, see [Read repair in Cassandra](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/operating/read_repair.html). Cheers!

Comment: Hi Erick, thank you for your answer. I don't understand when read repair chance triggers a read repair. However is it possible to disable all read repairs ? Cheers

Comment: Pas de problème, mon plaisir! 